# unable to load the mail client in iOS

Tags: objective-c, xcode, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I noticed that I am using the mail functionality several time so I decided to make an independent Class for functions that get repeated several time instead of copy-pasting the code several times

the class get successfully called and the e-mail function get successfully called as well but the e-mail client of the phone does not appear after the function is called

here is my code

in the main class I do the following call

```
-(void)emailFunction{
...

CommonlyUsed Email = [[CommonlyUsed alloc] init];
[Email sendMail:receipient :CC :BCC :subject :body];

...
}
```

in my CommonlyUsed.h I have the following IDEs called :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>


@interface CommonlyUsed : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>{
```

in CommonlyUsed.m I have the following :

```
-(void)sendMail:(NSString*)receipient:(NSString*)cc:(NSString*)bcc:(NSString*)subject:(NSString*)body{

 MFMailComposeViewController *composer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [ composer setMailComposeDelegate:self];

 if ( [MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){
if (receipient) {
            [composer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:receipient, nil]];
        }

        if (cc) {
            [composer setCcRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:receipient, nil]];
        }

        if (bcc) {
            [composer setBccRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:receipient, nil]];
        }

        if (subject) {
             [composer setSubject:subject];
        }

 [composer setMessageBody:body isHTML:HTMLBody];

        [composer setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];

        [self presentModalViewController:composer animated:YES];
        }
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {
    if(error){
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"error" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"error %@", [error description]] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
    else{
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }

    }
```

the code compiles and runs without errors what am I missing ??

Comment: Have you checked the value of `[MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]`?

Comment: Yes , it returns YES and it goes inside the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing this:

`[self presentModalViewController:composer animated:YES];`

do this:

`[[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController] presentModalViewController:composer animated:YES];`

or this:

`[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] presentModalViewController:composer animated:YES];`

Your class Email is not currently an active view controller so it can't present a modal view controller, you need to use an active one, like the rootViewController of the main UIWindow.

**EDIT**:

If your using ARC by the time the emailClient gets dismissed your object(delegate) would have been removed from memory, so a solution is to make the CommonlyUsed class a Singleton:

```
+(CommonlyUsed *)sharedInstance {

    static CommonlyUsed * cu = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{

        cu = [[CommonlyUsed alloc] init];

    });

    return cu;
}
```

So you would use it this way:

```
CommonlyUsed * email = [CommonlyUsed sharedInstance];
[email sendMail:receipient :CC :BCC :subject :body];
```

Comment: it Works!
now the application initiates the mail client but the 'didFinishWithResult' does not get called when I send the e-mail or cancel the e-mail sending , any way to fix this ?

Comment: Are you sure that the email object is still alive when the user dismisses the mailClient, from your code (If you're using arc) it looks like the email object is removed from memory when the method `-(void)emailFunction` returns.

A simple fix is to make your CommonlyUsed class a singleton.

Comment: everything works perfectly fine!!!!

the only thing I had to edit is the `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` to `[[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

You send `presentModalViewController:` to your instance `Email` of class `CommonlyUsed`, but this instance is not a view controller in the view hierarchy.

You must send `presentModalViewController:` to your currently active view controller.